# Reveal in Finder from the Terminal

Tags: terminal, finder

How do I reveal a file that I have the path for in the Terminal in Finder? I don't think that `open` will work for this.

Specifically I want to be able to `fzf` for a file and then pop it in Finder.

(I guess this would work if you get the path, chop off the file bit and then call open on the rest?)

Comment: `fzf` is not a default or native **macOS** _command line utility_, so   you might want to expound on "Specifically I want to be able to fzf for a file and then pop it in Finder.".

Comment: Here's a useful discussion of fzf:   https://superuser.com/questions/817351/how-to-use-fzf-on-mac-terminal-with-bash

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> How do I reveal a file that I have the path for in the Terminal in Finder? I don't think that open will work for this.

From `man open`:

```
-R  Reveals the file(s) in the Finder instead of opening them.
```

So, `open -R /path/to/a/file.ext` will reveal your file in the Finder...

> Specifically I want to be able to fzf for a file and then pop it in Finder.

In its most basic usage the following will reveal in Finder the file selected from the execution of `"$(fzf)"`:

```
open -R "$(fzf)"
```

The following `fzf` key bindings will map `ctrl-r` to reveal the file in the Finder and `ctrl-space` to a QuickLook of the file:

```
fzf --bind 'ctrl-r:execute(open -R {}),ctrl-space:execute-silent(qlmanage -p {})'
```

Comment: The `fzf` bindings are a great touch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have a relative path try this.

```
open relative/path/to/my_file.txt/..
```

Note the last three characters `/..`

This opens Finder with the parent directory of `my_file.txt`.

Comment: It works with relative paths, not with absolute ones. May still be worth posting it though

Comment: Using `open -R`, as in the accepted answer, is much better as it actually highlights the target _file_ in the opened **Finder** _window_ whether using absolute or relative _paths_, not just opening the _folder_ of the target _file_, then having to look for the target _file_ as this answer forces one to do.

Answer (score -2):

If you're in the directory (presumably you are) type

```
% pwd | pbcopy
```

then open  Finder, press  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> to  "Go to Folder", paste  and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

The  `open` command as  detailed by [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402796/119271) is the fastest and easiest   my  opinion, I just wanted to provide you with an alternate method to highlight some features of  macOS users may not be aware of:

- `pcbopy` utility that sends input to the clipboard
- Keyboard shortcut to open folder directly in  Finder

Comment: This does not reveal the file.

Comment: You know the file name right?  Type the first couple of chars.

Comment: Very weak as an answer, but very nice as a PSA for `pbcopy`.

Comment: I'm looking for an automated solution not a basic user guide to macOS.